# Specific-Length Int Arrays in Class Object

Tags: c#, arrays, class

So, this is related to a question I asked last night about the same code section - the question itself is not a duplicate.

In the following code, the `int[]` in `DamageTypeArray` will always be an `int[12]`.  Is there a way to specify this in the class to ensure it's always exactly the length that I need it to be?

```
public class DamageVehicle
{
    public int DVehicleID {get; set;}
}

public class DamageTypeArray
{
    public int[] DTypeArray {get; set;}
}

public class DamagePackage
{
    DamageVehicle dv;
    DamageTypeArray dta;
    DamagePackage dp;
}
```

For an object that has an instance of `DamagePackage`, could I reference it like this:

```
DamagePackage dp = new DamagePackage();

dp.dta[0] = 15;

dp.dta[1] = dp.dta[0] - 5;
```

If not, what method could I use so access the fixed length array in such a way?

Comment: Use a collections instead.

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead. If you really need to enforce the size constraint, you could write a `FixedLengthList<T>` class that inherits from `List<T>`, takes a size in its constructor, and throws an exception on Add, Remove, AddRange, RemoveAt, etc.

Comment: Initialize your `DTypeArray` in the class constructor.

Comment: I love collections, but in this case they don't really work for what I'm trying to accomplish.  I could make them work, but they wouldn't work as well.  In the end, there will be constants that will equate to each position, so I'll be calling `dp.dta[TEST_CASE]` or the like, and those will be modified sometimes if the object is passed to another actor.

Comment: @Pikoh - I was trying to do that, but there were compiler exceptions.  Can't say what off hand as I'm at work, but it wasn't okay with it at all.

Comment: So use a Dictionary or Hashtable

Comment: I use Dictionaries like a madman in many places, but in this particular case it just eats away at the readability of things more than I'd like when a lot of work is being done on the particular object inside an instance of the DamagePackage object.  At least, the readability from a personal perspective.  Plus, I'm comfortable with collections - trying to do something new (and functional) in production code.  Always good to learn new ways of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You can specified in the constructor of the class. Make the setter private so it can be changed out of the object.

```
public class DamageTypeArray
{
    public DamageTypeArray ()
    {
         DTypeArray = new int[12];
    }
    public int[] DTypeArray {get; private set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I would mark a backing field as `readonly` and initialize it to your array, and then override the indexer.

```
public class DamageTypeArray
{
    private readonly int[] _dTypeArray = new int[12];

    public int this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            return _dTypeArray[key]
        }
        set
        {
            _dTypeArray[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the getters and setters there you could add some validation to either return a default if the key is out of range or throw a more specific exception than "IndexOutOfRangeException".

To use this just utilize DamageTypeArray as if it were the array directly.

```
var damageArray = new DamageTypeArray();
damageArray[10] = 99999;
```

Alternatively you can just set a default value for the auto property.

```
public int[] DTypeArray { get; set; } = new int[12];
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  I feel like I tried this and it didn't work, but now I'm not so sure.  Thanks!

Comment: If you tried it and got a specific exception go ahead and post it here. Two things that may have gone wrong: 1) you can't set defaults for static fields 2) If you override the getter and setter you need to set the default on the backing field not on the property.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructor for array lenth:

```
public class DamageTypeArray
{
    public int[] DTypeArray {get; set;}
    public DamageTypeArray()
    {
        DTypeArray = new int[12];
    }
}
```

and use it like this `dp.dta.DTypeArray[0] = 15;`

Comment: Makes the code a little less readable, but it's not completely awful I suppose.  This might work.